# проблема с структурой

Tags: c, sqlite, struct

Использую структуру которую передаю в функцию (тестирую бд sqlite).Когда все переменые в структуре были типа `char*` проблем не было, но когда начал менять типы программа начала вылетать при записи в бд.

```
struct Report{
        int time;
        char *recipe_operator;
        int fraction_1;
        int fraction_2;
        int fraction_3;
        int fraction_4;
        int fraction_5;
        int fraction_6;
        float bitumen;
        int cellulose_1;
        int cellulose_2;
        int dust;
        int mixing_time;
        int temperature;
        int temperature_bitumen;
    };
```

запись в бд:

```
int insertData(char* databaseName, char* tableName, struct Report *strReport){

dbOpenResult = openDatabase(databaseName);
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
    "INSERT INTO '%q' "
        "('%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q') "
    "VALUES ("
        "'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q');"
        , tableName
        , SCHEME_ID
        , SCHEME_TIME
        , SCHEME_RECIPE_OPERATOR
        , SCHEME_FRACTION_1
        , SCHEME_FRACTION_2
        , SCHEME_FRACTION_3
        , SCHEME_FRACTION_4
        , SCHEME_FRACTION_5
        , SCHEME_FRACTION_6
        , SCHEME_BITUMEN
        , SCHEME_CELLULOSE_1
        , SCHEME_CELLULOSE_2
        , DUST
        , MIXING_TIME
        , TEMPERATURE
        , TEMPERATURE_BITUMEN
        , strReport->time
        , strReport->recipe_operator
        , strReport->fraction_1
        , strReport->fraction_2
        , strReport->fraction_3
        , strReport->fraction_4
        , strReport->fraction_5
        , strReport->fraction_6
        , strReport->bitumen
        , strReport->cellulose_1
        , strReport->cellulose_2
        , strReport->dust
        , strReport->mixing_time
        , strReport->temperature
        , strReport->temperature_bitumen);

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK){
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}else{
    fprintf(stdout, "Record created successfully\n");
}
sqlite3_close(db);

return 0;
}
```

Передаю такую структуру во время выполнения програмы:

```
//for test
    struct Report *reportStruct;
    reportStruct->time = 12213233;
    reportStruct->recipe_operator = "OPERATOR_1";
    reportStruct->fraction_1 = 100;
    reportStruct->fraction_2 = 20;
    reportStruct->fraction_3 = 32;
    reportStruct->fraction_4 = 34;
    reportStruct->fraction_5 = 54;
    reportStruct->fraction_6 = 64;
    reportStruct->bitumen = 29,4;
    reportStruct->cellulose_1 = 0;
    reportStruct->cellulose_2 = 0;
    reportStruct->dust = 0;
    reportStruct->mixing_time = 30;
    reportStruct->temperature = 26;
    reportStruct->temperature_bitumen = 153;
    //

    insertData(DB_NAME, TABLE_NAME, reportStruct);
```

Comment: А где выделяется память под объект структуры? В том виде, как вы представили код, указатель reportStruct имеет неопределенное значение.

Comment: struct Report *reportStruct;
reportStruct = malloc(sizeof(reportStruct)); Сделал так но проблемы это не решило

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные аргументы `sqlite3_mprintf` должны иметь тип `char *`, а у вас некоторые из них имеют тип `int`.
Можете использовать функцию `char *itoa(int)` из stdlib.h

Comment: Да вы правы, невнимательно смотрел документацию